# Puppet pluginfacts 404

Tags: puppet

I'm using puppet 6.10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and when I run puppet agent -t  on a server I get the below output

```sh
Info: Using configured environment 'dev'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment dev source(s) puppet:///pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment dev source(s) puppet:///plugins
Notice: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter]: Dependency File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/package_provider.rb]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/pe_version.rb]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/puppet_settings.rb]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
...lots more skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/puppet/type/file_line.rb]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Info: Retrieving locales
Error: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/locales]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment dev source(s) puppet:///locales
Notice: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/locales/ja]: Dependency File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/locales] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/locales/ja]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/locales/ja/puppetlabs-ntp.po]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Warning: /File[/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/locales/ja/puppetlabs-stdlib.po]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for web-dev.domain.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1571827736'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

I run with debug and the following strikes as interesting

```sh
Debug: HTTP GET https://puppetmaster01:8140/puppet/v3/file_metadata/pluginfacts returned 404 Not Found
Debug: HTTP GET https://puppetmaster01:8140/puppet/v3/file_metadata/plugins returned 404 Not Found
Debug: HTTP GET https://puppetmaster01:8140/puppet/v3/file_metadata/locales returned 404 Not Found
```

My site.pp

```
node 'default' {
  include common
}

# agent 
node /web[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+.domain.com/ {
  package {
    'openssh-server':
      ensure => latest,
  }
}

# not using regex to confirm that the FQDN is correct
node /web-dev.domain.com/ {
  include common
}
```

Not sure where to go from here or why I'm getting the 404 errors

Comment: This sounds like something went wrong with the Puppet Master install, or that firewall rules are not set up/ports issue. Regardless, you will probably have better luck on Server Fault.

Comment: Is the master also at version 6?  Is the `puppetdb` service running (or have you configured the master not to use it)?  Do the master's logs tell you anything relevant?

Comment: I was not using puppetdb. I removed everything and installed puppet from the ubuntu repos instead and it's now working fine

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was mis-matched versions

Comment: This answer should probably be written as a comment instead.